# what will happen if sending multiple web request for the same remote image on a android client

Tags: android, imageview

suppose that the same image will be displayed in different locations in a view. what is the best strategy to download images in this situation?

1. should I download just one image and save it as a cache or
2. should I just set the src of all ImageViews to the same URL and leave the Android system to handle it? or
3. if you are kind to suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for such things. I don't want to "promote" the library. But Glide is a established lib in the Android development environment. Many many Android devs (and big companies) use it. Whatever. Glide brings a build in cache. Additional you can customize it. See [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) for more about caching in Glide.

Maybe you think that using a library for "just downloading an image and display it on a `ImageView`" is "overkilled". But have you ever downloaded and displayed a image in a `ImageView` in a `List`/`RecyclerView`? 
Trust me. It's a pain to do it manually. Glide will help you with such things as well.

Here is a simple example (stolen from their [`Readme`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md)) to download a image from the given URL and put it into an `ImageView`:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/qFeBmOF.png").into(imageView);
}
```